# Can not call Function in Powershell but can with Powershell ISE

Tags: windows, function, powershell, call

i can not call a In-Script Function without PowerShell ISE

When i call a function in the normal Powershell i get this Error

```html
onboarding : The term "onboarding" was not used as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or
of an executable program. Check the spelling of the name or if the path is correct (if
included) and repeat the process.
In *************************************.ps1:8 characters:9
+ onboarding
+ ~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo : ObjectNotFound: (onboarding:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: Well, is the script loaded?

Comment: Yes it is. 
That's why i wonder
I also did  Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process -ExecutionPolicy Bypass.

Comment: I'm sorry, but there isn't nearly enough information to help you out here. So you dot sourced the script, and the function doesn't work after? Are you sure it's not an alias set elsewhere? Would recommend try asking on super user instead

Comment: The error is thrown at line 8, so I'm assuming the function definition occupies the 7 lines above it? PowerShell is largely interpreted, so if you're calling `onboarding` on line 8 but have placed the function definition in the same script file _after line 8_, then it won't be able to resolve it.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen, but, would a function defined below a usage work in ISE? Shouldn't it work the same as from a console?

Comment: @lit Yes, it might very well. When you use F5 to run a script in ISE, it doesn't actually invoke the script, it executes the contents of the editor in the global scope of the attached console/runspace, so it'll persist after the first attempt

Comment: Run your script using [Dot sourcing operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7#dot-sourcing-operator-). Then any functions, aliases, and variables that the script creates are added to the current scope, overriding existing ones.

Comment: @JosefZ this one worked thx. ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have in mind [Mathias R. Jessen's useful comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70850712/can-not-call-function-in-powershell-but-can-with-powershell-ise?noredirect=1#comment125254792_70850712) (valid for `▶` button as well):

> When you use <kbd>F5</kbd> to run a script in ISE, it doesn't actually
> invoke the script, it executes the contents of the editor in the
> global scope of the attached console/runspace, so it'll persist after
> the first attempt.

Run your script using [Dot sourcing operator `.`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-5.1#dot-sourcing-operator-)

> Runs a script in the current scope so that any functions, aliases, and
> variables that the script creates are added to the current scope,
> overriding existing ones. Parameters declared by the script become
> variables. Parameters for which no value has been given become
> variables with no value. However, the automatic variable `$args` is
> preserved.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> . c:\scripts\sample.ps1 1 2 -Also:3
> ```
>
> Note. *The dot sourcing operator is followed by a space. Use the space
> to distinguish the dot from the dot (`.`) symbol that represents the
> current directory.*